# angular accordion - `isFirstOpen` when `is-open` already in use

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui

Not sure how to even write about this issue. What do I do when I need two `is-open`?

I tried adding `is-open` twice (`<accordion-group is-open="status.open" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">` because I want the first to be open on load. But cause I was using `is-open` twice it's not working.

I then tried `<accordion-group is-open="status.open || status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">` That also does not work.

Here's a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/EYBHLXYCuAZbJwparO6u?p=preview

So, the top accordion group is not working at all right now, I'm trying to get it to open on page load. But really I want to eliminate that top accordion group altogether and just have the dynamic one below, but have the first dynamic accordion open on page load. I'm stuck as to how to proceed right now.

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="status.open || status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled"
        <accordion-heading><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i>
            I can have markup, as well! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open2, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open2}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        This is just some more content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </accordion-group>

    <accordion-group is-open="status.open2" ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <accordion-heading><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i>
           {{group.title}}<i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
       {{group.content}}
    </accordion-group>

  </accordion>
</div>
```

Comment: why not `is-open="status.open || status.isFirstOpen"`?  It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: That would be nice and simple, unfortunately it didn't work :( . I'm trying to combine using the chevon icons and the plus sign with the first open code.

Comment: You can't use `is-open` twice. what are you trying to combine ?

Comment: @JossefHarush Thanks all, plunker and more info provided above in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## http://plnkr.co/edit/wEoyhKK4h0aslEdcGSJY?p=preview

Add `isOpen:true` to the first item in the list

```
  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      content: 'content 1',
      isOpen: true
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      content: '<li>Content 2</li>'
    },
    ...
  ];
```

then change your html to this:

```
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    
      <accordion-group is-open="group.isOpen" ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <accordion-heading><i class="glyphicon-plus"></i> {{group.title}}
          <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !group.isOpen}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        {{group.content}}
      </accordion-group>

    </accordion>
  </div>
```

---

[image]

#### http://plnkr.co/edit/wEoyhKK4h0aslEdcGSJY?p=preview

Comment: Thanks much. Brilliantly simple solution. Angular... Why does it take so long to learn?! :headaches: